Role of friction in pure rolling
Consider a sphere performing pure rolling on a rough surface. The velocity of centre of mass of sphere is towards right and it has a clockwise angular velocity, with acceleration of centre of mass $a$ and angular acceleration $\alpha$ clockwise (see figure). 
Now, if the sphere is performing pure rolling:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
v = R \omega,
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $v$ indicates the velocity of centre of mass, and
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
a = R \alpha.
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
What is the role of friction acting on the sphere? If we monitor the contact point $P$ (on the sphere), the only force in horizontal direction is the frictional force, and since there is a net external unbalanced force in the horizontal direction, there must be a tangential acceleration in that direction. But, that is contradictory with Equation \eqref{eq:2}!

After a roller reaches pure roll, friction serves only to convert between linear and rotational kinetic energy to keep the pure roll condition. In your flat ground case, it can vanish because it is no longer needed after it had already achieved pure roll, because there is no tendency to change away from pure roll.

actually what you're saying is quite contradictory to what my professor has taught

no,wait a sec
if the object is performing pure rolling then there is a static friction right?

If the ball is accelerated, we have in a ideal case: $$F-f = ma = m\alpha R$$where $F$ acts on the centre of mass, and $f$ is the friction force acting on the contact point. As $\tau = fR = I\alpha$, where $I$ is the moment of inertia, the angular acceleration is determined:
$$\alpha = \frac{F}{\frac{I}{R} + mR}$$Also the acceleration:$$a = \frac{F}{\frac{I}{R^2} + m}$$
Note that if there was no rolling, just slipping on a frictionless surface, the first term of the denominator would not exist, and we would have the second law of Newton for a particle.

Consider a sphere in space that has no external forces acting on it, that has constant linear and angular momentum. The sphere doe not require an external force to keep rotating. We can arrange for the linear velocity to be just the right amount so that $v = R\omega$. In this case the sphere will continue to roll with no friction involved. If the sphere is rolling on a real surface on Earth, that has no friction and if there is no air resistance, the sphere will continue to roll indefinitely without requiring any surface friction to maintain the angular momentum of the sphere. Friction is only required if the sphere is accelerating or decelerating, but not for constant velocity.
Rolling friction is unavoidable in a real life situation, due to indentation and hysteresis effects. A perfectly frictionless surface does not exist in a gravitational field. This will cause the linear and angular velocity of the sphere to slow down. For a realistic situation where the ball is rolling but slowing down there is a frictional force acting on the sphere.

oh okay so i think i've made some misconceptions
thanks

no,wait a sec if the object is performing pure rolling then there is a static friction right? –

The static friction acting on an object is proportional to the force that is trying to accelerate the object up to a threshold value. If there is no accelerating force and the velocity is constant, the static friction is zero.

If there is rolling friction, it will act to slow down the sphere.

An important point is that for a circular object rolling at a constant speed, each outer point tends to be moving vertically downward when it contacts the ground, and then that point rises vertically upward immediately after it separates from the ground. So there’s no tendency for horizontal motion at the contact point that static friction would have to resist.
Why, then, do rolling objects slow down? Because other dissipative processes remain active—air resistance and internal friction (sometimes called mechanical hysteresis) of real, deformable objects on real, deformable surfaces.

Given the velocity $\mathbf{v}_G$, and the acceleration $\mathbf{a}_G = \dot{\mathbf{v}}_G$  of the center of mass and the angular velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, and the angular acceleration $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \dot{\boldsymbol{\omega}}$ of the sphere, the dynamical equations for momentum and angular momentum are
$$\begin{aligned}
m \mathbf{a}_G & = \mathbf{R}^{ext} = \mathbf{F} + \mathbf{C} \\
\mathbb{I}_G \cdot \boldsymbol{\alpha} & = \mathbf{M}^{ext}_G = \mathbf{M}_G + (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_G) \times \mathbf{C} \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
being $\mathbf{F}$, $\mathbf{M}_G$ the external "active" forces and moments referred to the center of gravity $G$, and $\mathbf{C}$ the reaction of the ground, as the vector sum of the normal reaction and the tangential static friction, $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{N} + \mathbf{F}^f = N \hat{\mathbf{z}} + \mathbf{F}^f$, with $\mathbf{F}^f \cdot \hat{\mathbf{z}} = 0$. It's possible to recast vector $\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q = -R \hat{\mathbf{z}}$.
A sphere has isotropic inertia tensor $\mathbb{I}_G = I_G \mathbb{I}$, being $\mathbf{I}$ the identity tensor, s.t. $\mathbb{I}_G \cdot \mathbf{w} = I_G \mathbb{I} \cdot \mathbf{w} = I_G \mathbf{w}$.
Now, let's write the angular velocity as the product of its module and the unit-vector defining its direction, $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \alpha \hat{\mathbf{n}}$, and assume that the sphere is not spinning in the direction orthogonal to the ground, $\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{z}} = 0$.
Let's define a third vector $\hat{\mathbf{t}} = \hat{\mathbf{z}} \times \hat{\mathbf{n}}$, s.t. $\mathbf{C} = N \hat{\mathbf{z}} + F^f_n \hat{\mathbf{n}} + F^f_t \hat{\mathbf{t}}$.
Let's project the two vector equations along the 3 directions $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$, $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, $\hat{\mathbf{t}}$,
$$\begin{aligned}
 z&: \quad \ \ 0 = F_z + N \\
 n&: m a_n = F_n + F^f_n \\
 t&: m a_t \ = F_t + F^f_t \\
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
 z&: \quad \ \ 0  = M_z + 0 \\
 n&: I_G \alpha \ = M_n + R F^t \\
 t&: \quad \ \ 0  = M_t - R F^n \\
\end{aligned}$$
If we assume now that the only external active force is the weight, applied to $G$, $\mathbf{F} = - m g \mathbf{\hat{z}}$, $\mathbf{M}_G = \mathbf{0}$, the equations become
$$\begin{aligned}
 z&: \quad \ \ 0 = -mg + N \\
 n&: m a_n = F^f_n \\
 t&: m a_t \ = F^f_t \\
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}
 z&: \quad \ \ 0  = 0 + 0 \\
 n&: I_G \alpha \ = 0 + R F^f_t \\
 t&: \quad \ \ 0  = 0 - R F^f_n \\
\end{aligned}$$
so that
$$\begin{aligned}
  & N = m g \\
  & F^f_n = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad a_n = 0 \\
  & F^f_t = m a_t = \frac{I_G}{R} \alpha \ .
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, if the "tangential" component of friction is proportional to the acceleration of the center of mass and to the angular velocity in the orthogonal direction.
